# Would I be allowed to sell my Chametz alcohol during the Prohibition?

Tags: halacha, passover, selling-mechirat-chametz, dina-dmalchusa-dina

During the [Prohibition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_in_the_United_States) in the United States, owning alcohol was permitted, though selling it was prohibited.

If I had a barrel of Vodka which I bought before the prohibition was made law, would I be allowed to sell it to a non-Jew for Pesach (Dina Demalchusa)?

Comment: What's the Vodka made of?

Comment: Can you think of any reason that you would be able to?

Comment: vodka in a barrel?

Comment: @DoubleAA some Poskim place limits on Dina Demalchuta.

Comment: @SethJ grain....

Comment: @Dan where do you store a lot of it? Maybe it was a large glass barrel?

Comment: I never seem to be able to keep a lot of it around. I'd think glass over wood (which would impart a flavor). No Sherry Cask issues with vodka.

Comment: What about selling it to a Canadian?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman The prohibition was on manufacture and sale - there was no law on purchasing or ownership.

Comment: I feel like this is a question about American law during Prohibition. How is this an halakhic question?

Comment: @ShimonbM Dina DeMalchusa

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it would be permitted because enforcement of prohibition was selective and selective enforcement is one of the things that nullifies Dina Demalchusa.

The selective enforcement was for two reasons: there was insufficient manpower to do better, and states had no interest in doing it, leaving the job to federal agents.

So a local officer would ignore the violation, but a federal one would not.