# Alcohol sales despite government monopoly

Tags: kashrut-kosher, transactions, grapes-wine, liquor-beer, dina-dmalchusa-dina

Many places have government imposed [alcohol monopolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_monopoly) and private retailers of alcoholic beverages are forbidden.

As alcohol, especially (red) wine, has a central place in Jewish practice and as such regulations therefore would prevent Jewish practice<sup>1</sup>, one may be tempted to say that *dina d'malchusa dina* ("the law of the land is the law") [does not apply](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27889/3073).

I have observed<sup>2</sup> orthodox *kehillos* (congregations) that have their own alcohol stores, thus circumventing the governmental restrictions.

**But here is the catch:** Besides the multitude of alcoholic drinks that do not require certification, many of the monopolies do in fact carry impressive lines of kosher products with easy ways to find them. Examples:
[British Columbia](http://www.bcliquorstores.com/product-catalogue?cert=kosher): 21 products; 21000 Jews
[Manitoba](http://www.liquormarts.ca/search-products/%25/kosher): 23 products; 13000 Jews
[Ontario](http://www.lcbo.ca/lcbo/search/filter?showAll=kosher): 77 products; 212000 Jews
[Pennsylvania](http://www.finewineandgoodspirits.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogSearchResultView?tabSel=2&level1=O_Kosher): 135 products; 293000 Jews
[Quebec](http://www.saq.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplay?storeId=20002&pageSize=100&searchTerm=kosher): 78 products; 95000 Jews
[Sweden](https://www.systembolaget.se/?otherselections=%5EKosher%24&fullassortment=1): 16 products, 20000 Jews

Even areas with very few Jews have at least something to offer:
[The Faroe Islands](http://www.rusan.fo/ShopItem/REYDVIN/0/01-804087/STK): at least<sup>3</sup> 1 product; no known Jews
[Finland](https://www.alko.fi/en/search/products/?tags=(2847)): 7 products, 1500 Jews
[Norway](http://www.vinmonopolet.no/vareutvalg/sok?query=kosher): 3 products; 1700 Jews
[Novo Scotia](http://www.mynslc.com/Pages/advancedSearch.aspx?k=kosher): 2 products; 3700 Jews

#### My questions

I have lived in Sweden, Minnesota, and Quebec a total of 10 years, but never heard of any religious exemptions there.

In a place that does not grant religious exemption, what *hetter* (halachic permission) is there to sell restricted alcohol?

If there is no such *hetter*, is it then permitted for an observant Jew<sup>4</sup> to buy from such outlets?

---

<sub>1. Well, at least according to [those that do not](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56911/3073) accept grape juice as an allowable substitute.</sub>
<sub>2. To avoid legal and halachic implications, I will not be more specific.</sub>
<sub>3. No *kosher* label or keyword to search for.</sub>
<sub>4. This is not a request for a *p'sak* (ruling), as I do not drink alcohol.</sub>

Comment: Related: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/religious-exemption-from-alcohol-monopolies

Comment: As an example, the law in Pennsylvania explicitly allowed religious institutions to open a liquor store for "sacramental" purposes. Thus, the received a license from the state to sell wine for the purpose of kiddush. This was similar to the exemption granted to the Catholic church for their use of wine. This is from memory when I visited my in-laws in Pittsburgh Pennsylvania. I am leaving this a comment for now as I do not have an explicit citation.

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ Regarding your most recent revision, I made [this meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3924/1713).

Comment: @sabbahillel see § 11.82.b [here](http://www.pacode.com/secure/data/040/chapter11/chap11toc.html).  I live in Pittsburgh and get my wine at Kosher Mart; the state store carries Manischevitz.  I used to have to fill out a form with every purchase giving my name, address, and congregation, but that stopped several years ago -- not sure why.

Comment: @MonicaCellio As I recall the law was changed. When we used to visit my in-laws in the 5730's and 40's we had to get our wine that way. I think from Pinskers (??)

Comment: @sabbahillel probably Pinskers. They still sell wine, and I think it's actually their wine that's in Kosher Mart (oh all right, Murray Ave. Kosher) up the street a couple blocks.  I think the process change happened about 10 years ago, give or take a couple.  I was definitely filling out forms as late as the early 5760s, maybe later.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** The question was edited to add the idea that in places **without** a "religious exemption" is there a heter to purchase from a shul.

Before one can discuss that, one would need to determine that the shul involved is indeed violating the law both as written and as practiced in that jurisdiction. While this would seem to be a "dina d'malchusa dina" and a "Chillul Hashem" issue, One would first need to answer questions that would determine if the question applies. As a result, one first must determine that there is indeed **no** "religious exemption" for **any** religion and what the practice is for other religions. Then one can see if this is a "religious persecution" situation or not.

The answer for that situation is that **usually** there would be a discussion which would involve the "sacramental wine" used by the Catholic Church in its religious rituals. These laws would seem to be written in such a way as to include the synagogue.

Since the question involves specific locations (such as Quebec) , the answer would be to ask the rav of a specific shul that seems to sell wine exactly what the situation is (and what are the applicable laws) in that location.

I have come across locations in which the shul is (as an example) allowed to stock wine bought at the "State Store" for repurchase of its congregants (as a service to those congregants).

As I said each location is different and would have to be looked into. One cannot give a general answer because each case can be different.

Also note the citation below in which the defacto behavior of the locality has "always been" to assume a "religious exemption" exists and the courts have accepted this even if a specific exemption was not written into the law. If this was done in practice, then it is best to keep quiet and not bring the subject up. After all, if it becomes known, it could cause a fuss and "the Jews" would be blamed both for "evading the law" and for removing the "religious exemption" that the non-Jews have "always" enjoyed.

---

**Original Answer**

When I visited Pittsburgh Pennsylvania, there was a religious exemption for sale of wine for "sacramental purposes" as long as the store was connected to a synagogue or church.

Thanks to @MonicaCellio for the reference to [SACRAMENTAL WINE LICENSEES](http://www.pacode.com/secure/data/040/chapter11/subchapCtoc.html)

> § 11.82. Sale and delivery.
>
> (a)  Sales of sacramental wine may be made only to an ordained
>   priest, clergyman or rabbi in charge of a congregation, for use in the
>   cathedral, church, synagogue or temple.
>
> (b)  Sales of sacramental wine may be made only to an ordained
>   priest, clergyman or rabbi in charge of a congregation, for the uses
>   of sustaining members of the congregation or members of the faith who
>   attend religious services where religious rites require the use of
>   sacramental wine in the home.
>
> (c)  The priest, clergyman or rabbi purchasing the wine shall furnish
>   to the licensee the name and address of the member or family and the
>   quantity of wine to be delivered. A sale or delivery may not occur
>   until the names and addresses have been certified to the licensee.
>
> (d)  The sales are limited to 40 liters annually per family.
>
> (e)  Deliveries shall be made by the licensee, directly to the home
>   address, as certified by the purchasing priest, clergyman or rabbi.
>
> Source
>
> The provisions of this §  11.82 adopted October 10, 1952; amended
>   September 29, 1978, effective September 30, 1978, 8 Pa.B. 2689.
>   Immediately preceding text appears at serial page (4213).

[Alcohol laws of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_laws_of_the_United_States) discusses exemptions for underage drinking for religious purposes.

[Religion and Prohibition](http://religionrogue.blogspot.com/2010/10/religion-and-prohibition.html)

> During Prohibition there were exemptions for sacramental wine and
>   other religious uses of alcohol. The Eighteenth Amendment, which took
>   effect in 1920, doesn't say anything about those exemptions. It just
>   says that the manufacture, sale or transportation of intoxicating
>   liquors within the United States is banned. It was federal legislation
>   that exempted religious uses from the laws.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/what-should-we-do-with-edits-to-questions-that-invalidate-answers-that-found-a-w#comment12084_3924

Comment: I don't think your update answers the question any more than the original answer did.

Comment: @Daniel I answered that one must determine the exact case and is this a case of shmad or not. Until that is done, there is no generic answer.